# Objective-C method overriding/overloading confusion

Tags: objective-c

There seems to be some debate/disagreement on whether it is possible to 'overload' methods in Objective-C. Putting aside that it is impossible to define method overloading in Objective-C is terms equal to those of C++ (because of method signature syntax differences), I would ask in particular: Which of the following is allowed and which are not?

1) A class declaring/implementing both these methods:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithObject:(ClassA*) object;
- (void) doSomethingWithObject:(ClassB*) object;
```

2) A class declaring/implementing both these methods:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithObject:(ClassA*) object;
- (BOOL) doSomethingWithObject:(ClassA*) object;
```

3) A class declaring/implementing this method:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithObject:(ClassB*) object;
```

...when its superclass declares/implements this method:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithObject:(ClassA*) object;
```

(and the analogue for conflicting return value), both when A) `ClassB` descends from `ClassA`, and B) Not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1: no can do: Objective-C doesn't include the types in the method names; there is no mangling. It might work with Objective-C++ -- never used it that much.

Question 2: Same. Won't work.

Question 3: Will work.

EDIT: in general, method names do not include any types, so if you strip the types and they are the same then it will be considered the same, and therefore won't be allowed in the same class. Along the same lines, it WILL work if it's in different classes, although you might get some confusion if the types used in the call and the types used in what gets called don't quite agree.

Comment: OK, so basically the string (e.g.)  "methodWithParam1:param2:param3:" (the 'selector') must be unique for each method in the same class, and changing argument type/ return type when sub classing (overriding) is OK?

Comment: It's quite likely that case 3 will generate a compiler warning. The superclass's method takes an instance of `ClassA`. That means that all objects of that class *and its subclasses* must accept any object of `ClassA` for the same method. This is necessary because an instance of a subclass may be used anywhere that an instance of the superclass could be. But you are trying to redeclare the method with a narrower requirement – that it only accepts objects of `ClassB`. It is correct that, at runtime, the method will get called, but whether it will work given what it's passed is another question.

Comment: I wonder What happens with UITableView's delegate property. It is supposed to override UIScrollView's delegate property, but it restricts it further to only accept objects that also conform to UITableViewDelegate protocol. I don't know the internals, but I'm sure you can't 'override' ivars. I assume the -setDelegate: propert accessor in UITableView imposes extra constrains in the parameter (argument) passed.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in terms of C++ where the compiler does the static binding of figuring out which instance method to call based on the type of the input.

Objective-C doesn't work that way.  Instead, all binding is dynamic at run-time.  Kinda like all methods being declared "virtual" in C++.  The programmer is responsible for passing in appropriate variables that respond in the way your method expects.

Your method could query the object being passed in whether it responds to certain selectors and take appropriate action based on that if you wanted more robust behavior.  Or your method could ask the object being passed in whether it is a type it expects.  Again, this would all be done at run-time in your method.  Not by the compiler.

So the answer is, declare as:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithObject:(id) object;
```

... then pass in whatever object you like.

Comment: Uh, no... I'm definitely NOT thinking in terms of C++. I just happen to know that the compiler DOES do some type checking (when you specify something other than 'id'), just didn't know the extent.